# How to take user input and insert it into a copy directory process in a Batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to cut the time it takes to set up Autodesk for the employees at work. To do this I needed to first map a network drive and then copy a couple of files from the network drive to Autodesk on the users C drive. However, since each PC will be different because it goes into the user profile; I had to make a input variable to take in the name.

This is what I have:

```
@echo Create new K: drive mapping
@net use K: \\vasalacad\autocad\library
@echo Enter User ID "firstname.lastname"
@set /p UserID=""
@copy /y "K:\setups\tmco1.dwt" "C:\Users\"UserID"\AppData\Local\Autodesk\AutoCAD Electrical 2015\R20.0\enu\Template"
@copy /y "K:\setups\BlackPlot.ctb" "C:\Users\"UserID"\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD Electrical 2015\R20.0\enu\Plotters\Plot Styles"
:exit
@pause
```

What I got was this:

> ```
> Create new K: drive mapping
> The command completed successfully.
> Enter User ID "firstname.lastname"
> ******.*******
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>         0 file(s) copied.
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>         0 file(s) copied.
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

I edited the user input so that I wouldn't display the name on the forums. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your env variable properly using `%`:

```
@copy /y "K:\setups\tmco1.dwt" "C:\Users\%UserID%\AppData\Local\Autodesk\AutoCAD Electrical 2015\R20.0\enu\Template"
@copy /y "K:\setups\BlackPlot.ctb" "C:\Users\%UserID%\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD Electrical 2015\R20.0\enu\Plotters\Plot Styles"
```

Alternately, you could provide the script to your users, and in that case, no interactions, and they would do (no need to mount a drive BTW):

```
@copy /y "\\vasalacad\autocad\library\setups\tmco1.dwt" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Autodesk\AutoCAD Electrical 2015\R20.0\enu\Template"
@copy /y "\\vasalacad\autocad\library\setups\BlackPlot.ctb" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD Electrical 2015\R20.0\enu\Plotters\Plot Styles"
```

OR: create a text file (here `users.txt`) containing 1 user per line and copy the files in a loop:

```
@echo off
set SRC=\\vasalacad\autocad\library\setups
for /F %%a in (users.txt) do (copy /y "%SRC%\tmco1.dwt" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Autodesk\AutoCAD Electrical 2015\R20.0\enu\Template"
copy /y "%SRC%\BlackPlot.ctb" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD Electrical 2015\R20.0\enu\Plotters\Plot Styles"
)
```